# Array data disappears - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, arrays, parse-platform

I'm trying to take data from a backend(I'm using parse.com), put it into an array and use it to populate a ListView via an adapter. I parse multiple objects into a list and then put "names" and "ids" into two separate string arrays.

Now, my problem is that data disappears as soon as I add the next position to the array. I've spent quite a while figuring this out with debug logs, and it appears as if names[0] is displayed in the log properly when requested right after I write it. If I try to access names[0] after writing names[1] I get a null pointer exception - println needs a message, and the app crashes. When not trying to access the data via debug log, the listview is populated by a proper number of entries, yet the data that should've come from names[] and ids[] is empty. Here's the code where everything goes horribly wrong:

```
 names =  new String[2];
    ids =  new String[2];
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("TestItem");

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {
                int size = objects.size();
                int i = 0;
                ParseObject obj;

                while (i < size) {
                obj = objects.get(i);
                names[i] = obj.getString("name");
                ids[i] = obj.getString("objectId");
                i++;
                }
                /*The following code is fairly irrelevant(I think?) since the error appears
                to be somewhere in the previous lines.*/
                Bundle bundel = new Bundle();
                bundel.putStringArray("names", names);
                bundel.putStringArray("ids", ids);
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                screen = new Feed().newInstance(bundel);
                ft.add(R.id.holder_frame, screen);
                ft.commit();
            } else {

            }

        }
    });
```

I feel like it's something basic about managing arrays, but I can't seem to understand it. Please help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line seems to be fishy:

```
new Feed().newInstance(bundel);
```

`newInstance` method should be static method.
Make sure that you are adding the appropriate instance of fragment with the bundle information. If you don't figure it out, provide code in the Fragment.

Consider code below:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("TestItem");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

        if (e == null) {
            int size = objects.size();

            String[] names =  new String[size];
            String[] ids =  new String[size];

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                ParseObject elem = objects.get(i);
                names[i] = elem.getString("name");
                ids[i] = elem.getObjectId();
            }

            /*The following code is fairly irrelevant(I think?) since the error appears
            to be somewhere in the previous lines.*/
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putStringArray("names", names);
            params.putStringArray("ids", ids);

            ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            screen = new Feed();
            screen.setArguments(params);

            ft.add(R.id.holder_frame, screen);
            ft.commit();
        } else {
            Toast.make(<Current>Activity.this, "Error", ...).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I will look into it, but there's something I need to specify here I suppose. The data disappears during the "while" cycle - names[0] becomes empty after names[1] has been written. This piece of code used to be in the fragment which hosted the ListView but the error was still there. I will edit the code piece to make it more clear.

Comment: I didn't pay that much attention to that. Why are you setting size of 2? If you get result of more than 2, you will easily get ```ArrayOutOfBoundException```

Comment: Just for the sake of testing, since I have exactly 2 entries in the database. I'm still learning, so ensuring that some parts of code cannot possibly cause an error in the current configuration helps a lot.

Comment: Looks like that worked the magic and fixed a couple other issues as well. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think this might be the problem:

```
int size = objects.size();
int i = 0;
ParseObject obj;

while (i < size) {
  obj = objects.get(i);
  names[i] = obj.getString("name");
  ids[i] = obj.getString("objectId");
  i++;
}
```

names and ids are initialised as

```
 names =  new String[2];
 ids =  new String[2];
```

You are looping over all of the elements in `objects` so if it has any more than two elements you will be writing outside the bounds of the `names` and `ids` arrays.

Comment: That's a temporary code, the test database has exactly two objects :) The person above seems to have already solved the issue!

Comment: No worries, just something that caught my eye. Glad you got it solved